# Issue with PHP script export CSV file Excel Mac 2016

Tags: php, csv, html-parsing, export-to-excel, excel-2016

I want to parse all cities from a website (which seems to be encoded `<meta charset="iso-8859-15" />`). Then I want to export them in CSV file in order to have them in Excel (Office for Mac 2016). I am using Simple HTML DOM Parser in my PHP script.

First, I coded a PHP script on PC with Windows. CSV file was OK and Excel recognized it correctly (Windows(ANSI) format). No problem here.

Nevertheless, it's a script I want to use on Windows and Mac. When I tested it on Mac, there were a lot of special characters inside. Here is an example of cities I got:

```
 Paris 15ème
 Brétigny-sur-Orge
 Paris 19ème
 Paris 5ème
 Argenteuil
 Saint-Mandé
```

I do not understand why 'è' (`&egrave;`) are in HTML format, while 'é' have good format.

Here is how I gather cities:

```
$place = str_replace('  ','',$lbc->find('div[class="placement"]',0)->plaintext);
```

To delete this coding problem, I tried to use html_entity_decode like this:

```
$place = str_replace('','',html_entity_decode($lbc->find('div[class="placement"]',0)->plaintext));
```

which made the job for 'è', 'ê', BUT then 'é' characters which were OK are not anymore, they become `?`.

I do not see how to handle all this.

Other issue, when I try to import CSV file in Excel Mac 2016, it does not recognized format. I have to open the CSV with Sublime Text 2 in order to find the good format,then save and finally import it in Excel for Mac.